# Console Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrolltop

I'm trying to get a div class to scroll to the top when `.recipeImgs li` is clicked. I tried the code below but i am getting the `error` message

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined". Not sure how to fix the issue
```

Thanks

```
$('.recipeImgs li').on('click',function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log("clicked");
      var target = this.hash,
      $target = $(target);

      $('html, body').stop().animate({
          'scrollTop': $target.offset().top-50
      }, 900, 'swing', function () {
          window.location.hash = target;
     });
});
```

Comment: if there are no elements in the `$target` then `$target.offset()` would return `undefined`.. also `li` element does not have a `hash` property...

Comment: please share you html code also

Comment: there is no `this.hash` for `li` element ... it can be used with elements like **anchor tag** which has `href` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

The issue, as someone pointed out in one of the comments, is that `$target` has no element, which means that the `.offset()` method returns `undefined`. Obviously there is no property `top` on `undefined`, hence the error.

You might reconsider writing your function something like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.recipeImgs li', function(evt){
  evt.preventDefault();

  var $target = $(this);

  if(!$target.length) return;

  $('html, body')
    .stop()
    .animate({
      'scrollTop': $target.offset().top - 50
    }, 900, 'swing', function(){
      window.location.hash = '[target]';
    })
});
```

This fixes several things. First of all, it delegates the listener to the `document`, so if your `li` is dynamically appended, you'll still be able to grab the event (as it bubbles up the DOM). There's also a check for `$target.length`. This just ensures that you don't try to retrieve the offset of an empty collection, resulting in an error and breaking your code.